# horizontally scrolling div problems with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, horizontal-scrolling

My page currently looks like this:

http://hscrollinghelp.tumblr.com/

When I click the work, it is perfectly scrolled to the work section. However, When I try to access the work section directly when loading the page by using http://hscrollinghelp.tumblr.com/#work , it seems **#work** replaces himself with **about**, which means I can't go back to **about**.

This is my CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body, ul, ol, li, form, fieldset, legend{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p { margin: 0; }

    body{
        font-family: 'Vollkorn', serif, Arial;
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 1.5;
    }

    p{
        margin-bottom:15px;
    }

    a{
        color:#0073BF;
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    h2{
        text-align:center;
        font-size:32px;
        font-weight:400;
    }

    h4{
        text-align:center;
        font-size:18px;
        font-weight:400;
    }

    #wrap{
        width:600px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

    #content{
        overflow:hidden;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #ccc;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #ccc;
        box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #ccc;
    }

    .contentbox-wrapper{
        position:relative;
        left:0;
        width:3000px;
        height:100%;
    }

    .contentbox{
        width:580px;
        height:100%;
        float:left;
        padding:10px;
        background:#fff;
    }

    #nav {
        margin-top:10px;
        background: url("navbg.png") repeat-x center bottom;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
        padding: 5px 10px;
    }

    #nav ul li{
        display:inline;
        margin-right:10px;
    }

</style>
```

This is the body:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="content">
            <div class="contentbox-wrapper">
                <div id="about" class="contentbox">
                    <h3>About</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed iaculis ornare nibh, vel condimentum risus blandit ut. Sed vel tortor ac ligula blandit interdum eu vel leo. In semper, nunc sit amet tincidunt volutpat, nisl elit tempor eros, at rutrum nisl enim a lorem. Ut quis tellus felis. Maecenas rhoncus accumsan odio quis faucibus. Aliquam erat tortor, vehicula eget facilisis eget, commodo et sapien. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent convallis urna non est mollis ultrices. Fusce fringilla lacinia sapien non eleifend. Morbi venenatis nulla id libero tempus et volutpat sem facilisis. Duis eu lacus sapien. Aliquam a lorem justo. Cras nec mi quam, vitae fermentum urna. </p>
                </div>
                <div id="work" class="contentbox">
                    <h3>Work</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed iaculis ornare nibh, vel condimentum risus blandit ut. Sed vel tortor ac ligula blandit interdum eu vel leo. In semper, nunc sit amet tincidunt volutpat, nisl elit tempor eros, at rutrum nisl enim a lorem. Ut quis tellus felis. Maecenas rhoncus accumsan odio quis faucibus. Aliquam erat tortor, vehicula eget facilisis eget, commodo et sapien. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent convallis urna non est mollis ultrices. Fusce fringilla lacinia sapien non eleifend. Morbi venenatis nulla id libero tempus et volutpat sem facilisis. Duis eu lacus sapien. Aliquam a lorem justo. Cras nec mi quam, vitae fermentum urna. </p>
                </div>

                <div id="contact" class="contentbox">
                    <h3>Contact</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed iaculis ornare nibh, vel condimentum risus blandit ut. Sed vel tortor ac ligula blandit interdum eu vel leo. In semper, nunc sit amet tincidunt volutpat, nisl elit tempor eros, at rutrum nisl enim a lorem. Ut quis tellus felis. Maecenas rhoncus accumsan odio quis faucibus. Aliquam erat tortor, vehicula eget facilisis eget, commodo et sapien. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent convallis urna non est mollis ultrices. Fusce fringilla lacinia sapien non eleifend. Morbi venenatis nulla id libero tempus et volutpat sem facilisis. Duis eu lacus sapien. Aliquam a lorem justo. Cras nec mi quam, vitae fermentum urna. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li ><a class="active" href="#about" onClick="goto('#about', this); return false">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#work" onClick="goto('#work', this); return false">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact" onClick="goto('#contact', this); return false">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And this is what my JavaScript looks like:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function goto(id, t){
        //animate to the div id.
        $(".contentbox-wrapper").animate({"left": -($(id).position().left)}, 600);
    }
```

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: @BenM So sorry, code's added.

Comment: Can you try ?
function goto(id, t){   
        //animate to the div id.
        $(".contentbox-wrapper").animate({"left": -($(t).position().left)}, 600);
        }
I just guess, this may not be corect.

Comment: It makes it scrolls and stops to a wrong place. :(